# How to fix build error because Install pods using EAS build EXPO?

Tags: expo

I'm trying to build an IOS app using EAS service expo, but when I try to build, there is an error while install pods on build details expo. And this is the error.

```
Unable to find a specification for `UMTaskManagerInterface` depended upon by `EXLocation`
```

I try to install pod by `npm i pod-install` but still get error. Is this because I build on Windows, or what should I do to fix this error? I also try to find the error in GitHub forum, and it's say adding path pod in `ios/Podfile` which I can't find it in my expo project. Where is ios/Podfile file located in expo project?

This is the full error

```
Installing pods
Using Expo modules
Auto-linking React Native modules for target `MMS`: RNCAsyncStorage, RNCCheckbox, RNDateTimePicker, RNGestureHandler, RNPermissions, RNReanimated, RNScreens, react-native-safe-area-context, and react-native-viewpager
Analyzing dependencies
Fetching podspec for `DoubleConversion` from `../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/DoubleConversion.podspec`
Fetching podspec for `RCT-Folly` from `../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/RCT-Folly.podspec`
Fetching podspec for `glog` from `../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/glog.podspec`
Adding spec repo `trunk` with CDN `https://cdn.cocoapods.org/`
CocoaPods 1.11.2 is available.
To update use: `sudo gem install cocoapods`
For more information, see https://blog.cocoapods.org and the CHANGELOG for this version at https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/releases/tag/1.11.2
[!] Unable to find a specification for `UMTaskManagerInterface` depended upon by `EXLocation`
You have either:
 * out-of-date source repos which you can update with `pod repo update` or with `pod install --repo-update`.
 * mistyped the name or version.
 * not added the source repo that hosts the Podspec to your Podfile.
[stderr] [!] `<PBXResourcesBuildPhase UUID=`13B07F8E1A680F5B00A75B9A`>` attempted to initialize an object with an unknown UUID. `2EE81B3C866A4A13B6460929` for attribute: `files`. This can be the result of a merge and the unknown UUID is being discarded.
pod exited with non-zero code: 1
```

Edit*
i try using `expo build:ios`-> archive is working perfectly. why using `eas build -p ios` i got that error?

Comment: Were you able to find an answer on this? I'm getting the same error.

Comment: Still not getting any answer yet, but I copy the whole project into the new clean project expo, install the newest EAS, and also use expo version 47. I'm not just copy-pasting the whole project but recreating the project, with the same asset, code, library, etc.
and it works.

Comment: I had a similar issue with another plugin. For me the solution was to run `expo prebuild`. This will generate an `android` folder and an `ios` folder. The `podfile` that you need to edit is then under the `ios` folder.  After you have made changes to the podfile, execute `expo prebuild` again.

Comment: @BruceHill hello but isnt expo prebuild the same as ejecting from expo? What if i do not want to eject from expo?

Comment: No, prebuild does not eject from expo.  It builds your android and ios folders so you can make changes before doing the actual build with EAS. It definitely does not eject from expo.